# Lack of data in getInvestmentPositions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm using the `getInvestmentPositions` API call and most of the responses we've received have almost no data, and return `inv_security_type` of "**OTHERINFO**". However, this information shows up without any problems on Mint.com.

How can we diagnose our lack of data using the API, and is there a support line I can call to more specifically troubleshoot this problem? We're running a financial services application and having accurate investment position data is critical for us, and we need to find a solution this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call 'updateInstitutionLogin' API with refresh flag set to true(PFB ref link). This will trigger an explicit refresh request to the FI. If this call gets successful then please verify if you are getting all the info by calling 'getInvestmentPositions' API.

Ref Link -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0075_updateinstitutionlogin

You can post this qts in IPP's live community as well.
https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/

If the above solution doesn't help, then they might need some more info for this usecase and give you the solution

Thanks

Comment: Hi @manas-mukherjee - we've called `updateInstitutionLogin` and are receiving the following message for all accounts: `<Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable 503 Code:DownStreamServiceUnavailable,Type:SYSTEM readbody=true>`  This applies to any account we've tried to refresh. Is there a support email address we can use to help diagnose this issue?

Comment: Please post this qts in IPP's LiveCommunity(https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/). Someone from CAD team will help you to resolve this issue. Thanks